# Is it possible to get a nice/super/excellent throw on Weedle?

Tags: pokemon-go

With Weedle being one of the most common pokémon for me, I realized that I never got a "nice", "great" or "excellent" throw on it, even though the animation looks like I hit inside the circle.

My guess is that Weedle is so "easy" that it is not possible to get a throw bonus on it. Or am I just that bad at throwing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten "nice" and "curveball" bonuses on weedles multiple times. 
I even got nice on him when I've thrown the ball a bit higher than needed and he jumped into it.

Answer (score 2):

Weedles are short, sit close to the player, and have the little spike on their heads that sits outside the circle that gets in the way,  so it's tricky to throw the ball low enough to hit them in the circle.

The best way I've found is, when you start spinning the ball for your curveball, instead of starting the throw from the centre of the screen, move the ball to the left hand corner (assuming you spin left and throw right)  and throw a short, flat, curveball from there - it's still a little tricky but you'll score a "great" around 50% of the time

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I am fairly certain that you can get nice, great and excellent throws on every Pokémon, however it isn't very easy.

The thing you should should try is imagining an underhanded-throw or a [basketball-three-pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-point_field_goal) trying to hit the Pokémon's chest. Also it is worth noting that the best point to throw the ball is when the Pokémon is inside the coloured circle, not when it's smallest.

Comment: Thanks. I know that it can be difficult and I guess that the problem with Weedle is that is so close to the player and I throw to hard all the time. I'm marking the other answer as correct, though, because it is a more definitive answer.